# JSON object within JSON objects in Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I am new to node.JS and currently working on a mini-project.
Problem Statement: I want to get the value of "window" but want to hide the key "window". Is there a way out for this in Node.js?

Input Json:

```
{
"widget": {
            "debug": {
                        "window": {
                                    "image": [
                                        { 
                                            "src": "Images/Sun.png",
                                            "name": "sun1",
                                            "hOffset": 250,
                                            "vOffset": 250,
                                            "alignment": "center"
                                        },
                                        { 
                                            "src": "Images/Moon.png",
                                            "name": "moon1",
                                            "hOffset": 250,
                                            "vOffset": 250,
                                            "alignment": "center"
                                        }
                                    ]
                               }
                    }
         }
}
```

Output Json:

```
 {
"widget": {
            "debug": {
                         "image": [
                                     { 
                                         "src": "Images/Sun.png",
                                         "name": "sun1",
                                          "hOffset": 250,
                                          "vOffset": 250,
                                          "alignment": "center"
                                       },
                                       { 
                                          "src": "Images/Moon.png",
                                          "name": "moon1",
                                          "hOffset": 250,
                                          "vOffset": 250,
                                          "alignment": "center"
                                        }
                                ]

                    }
         }
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "hide"?

Comment: @Kevin B i don't want "window" i.e. the key to be seen in the output JSON. Only its value has to be displayed.

Comment: So in other words you want to remove `widget.debug.window`, and store the `widget.debug.window.image` key/value pair on `widget.debug`.

Comment: Yes, you got it right

Comment: Easy, convert the json to an object, make the substitution, delete the window property, and then stringify it again.

Comment: @Kevin B can you answer the question and show me how to do it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var widget = JSON.parse(json_string);
var window_content = widget.debug.window;
widget.debug = window_content;
var new_json_string = JSON.stringify(widget);
```

edit: removed `widget.debug.window = false;` since replacing widget.debug will remove it, and setting it to false would make it appear again as "false".

Comment: note that you don't need window_content. `widget.debug = widget.debug.window`

Comment: @KevinB Yeah, you´re right :)

Comment: Also note that this will wipe any other possible keys of `widget.debug`. For example, if the original JSON data included a `widget.debug.foobar` entry, it would also be gone after running this code.